# sorting NSArray on ID

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I have an NSArray with statussen of people. (ex. Online, Offline,...) Now I got this from my core database. And that core database got the objects from a webservice. Now I need another status (Logout) to the end of my array. This is what I do in code.

```
_arrStatus = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (Status *status in matches) {
        [_arrStatus addObject:status];
    }
    BOOL logout = false;
    for (Status *status in matches) {
        if([status.cs_id isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]){
            logout = true;
        }
    }
    if(!logout){
        Status* newStatus = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Statussen" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        newStatus.cs_id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        newStatus.cs_name = @"Logout";
        [_arrStatus addObject:newStatus];
    } 
    NSError *error = nil;
    [context save:&error];
```

Like you can see I gave my 'Logout status' the ID 0, because I am sure that, that ID is available. Here is how to order of my NSArray and the ID's.

- Logout -> ID 0
- Online -> ID 1
- Offline -> ID 2
- Absent -> ID 3

Now I want my array to look like this.

- Online -> ID 1
- Offline -> ID 2
- Absent -> ID 3
- Logout -> ID 0

Anybody has an Id how I can do this?

Comment: can you post the log of your array?

Comment: why not use a dictionary if the id is unique ?

Comment: assign item at index 0 to tmp variable; remove item at index 0; add tmp variable to array. Maybe too 'Hardcoded'

Comment: You don't need a temporary variable, just add the object to the end of the array before you delete it from the front:
`[_arrStatus addObject:[_arrStatus objectAtIndex:indexToAddToEnd]];`
 `[_arrStatus removeObjectAtIndex:indexToAddToEnd];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
if(!logout){
    Status* newStatus = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Statussen" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    newStatus.cs_id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    newStatus.cs_name = @"Logout";
    [_arrStatus addObject:newStatus];
}
```

To this:

```
if(!logout){
    Status* newStatus = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Statussen" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    newStatus.cs_id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    newStatus.cs_name = @"Logout";
    [_arrStatus insertObject:newStatus atIndex:0];
}
```

To put the log in the front of the array.
Or if you need to sort the array you can use something like this:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [_arrStatus sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return (NSComparisonResult)[(Status*)obj1.cs_id compare:(Status*)obj2.cs_id];
}];
```